# MongoDB UTC DateTime Format To Local Time

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, utc

I am using MongoDB c# driver to insert data into MongoDB. When I pass DateTime it's automatically storing it in UTC Format. But i want to store that in Local UK time. How to set the field in MongoDB to save in local time format and how to change date that already exists in the MongoDB collection.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/DeOHnysSCOk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB provides an attribute which automatically does the trick.

```
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
```

might be helpful for someone.

Comment: Do you know if the Casbah (Scala) driver has this?